# Can't boot from Hard Drive after replacing OS with Ubuntu

Tags: boot, windows, drive

I uninstalled Windows 7 recently and installed Ubuntu 12.04 instead. However, after a successful installation, I could only boot from CD when I restarted my computer, which led to the screen asking if I wanted to try out Ubuntu, or install it (It was already installed though) How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

go into BIOS (often pressing F2 during startup) and navigate over to the "boot" menu.
in this menu, you can select which volume to be read on bootup by marking it and pressing F6 to move it up the list... the drive where you installed Ubuntu should be on top.
and remove the CD